# Woocommerce - disable «proceed to checkout» button in cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am currently trying to figure out a way to disable the «*proceed to checkout*» button for a specific situation: Some oversize products can cannot be shipped to certain countries, unless the client asks for a quote first.

I added a function in `functions.php` that detects these oversized products.

In the `cart-shipping.php` and `cart-totals.php`, I can't find the point where I should add the:

```
remove_action(woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
```

Is it possible to help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I finally found it, if anyone cares or need, just update the template\woocomerce\cart.php , for the input button / class="checkout-button"

Comment: This [link](http://www.bolderelements.net/support/knowledgebase/removing-checkout-button-shipping-not-available/) will help you may be

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout',
'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

I added to `woocommerce\templates\cart\proceed-to-checkout-button.php`
 a style: `style="display:none"`.. seems working for me.

```
a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() );?>" class="checkout-button 
button alt wc-forward" style="display:none"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also hide this button by CSS code.

```
a.checkout-button.button.alt.wc-forward {
display: none;}
```